# Насколько мой код приемлемый

Tags: android, инспекция-кода, kotlin, rxjava, rxandroid

Я только начал изучать Android и Rx, ещё не знаю всех тонкостей. Хотелось бы узнать, насколько ужасный блок кода.

```
val room = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java, "book-test3").build()

Thread {
    room.bookDao().insertAll(Book(name = "Name", author = "Author"))
    Observable.just(room.bookDao().getFist().author)
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe {
                hello.text = "Author $it"  // TextView.setText()
             }
}.start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы используете rx, то вам не надо использовать Trhead, rx все сделает.
Надо только указать `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`в цепочке операторов, для выполнения в фоне.
Также обернуть insert в `Observable`.
Для RxJava 1 будет так

```
Observable.create( {
    room.bookDao().insertAll(Book(name = "Name", author = "Author"))
    val author = room.bookDao().getFist().author
    it.onNext(author)
    it.onCompleted()
}, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            hello.text = "Author $it"
        }
```

А вообще, на сколько я знаю, [Room умеет работать с RxJava](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)
Если у вас RxJava 1, то советую сразу переходить на вторую версию.